# How to enable Windows Update over the internet for domain computers? (Code: 8024402C)

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Currently on a computer running Windows 7 on a domain the Windows Update does not run by itself because "You receive updates: Managed by your system administrator". The error code is 8024402C

Detail: Open Windows Update, there you see a red message "Windows could not search for new updates", Code 8024402C. Below there is an interesting message: "Your receive updates: Managed by your system administrator".

At the bottom there is a link "Check online for updates from Microsoft Update". If I click it it will work but I want the windows update to work by itself not manually.

This system is not connected to the domain most of the time (laptop).

In Microsoft knowledge-base they say that this is caused by WSUS (Windows  Server Update Services).

I want to have automatic updates from WU and WSUS in the same time. If this is not possible I would like to know how can I switch from WSUS to WU. I do have administrator account for local computer.

Comment: The reason MS doesn't allow both is because that defeats the whole purpose of a WSUS server on a domain. The purpose of the WSUS server is so IT can test the patches and verify them before they are approved to go out to the users. If you defeat the WSUS server, or allow the computer to just download patches straight from Windows Update you are are more likely to get a patch that will break something on your computer. Then you will be crying to the IT department that your computer doesn't work right when you were the one who did it. If you are having this issue, please work with your IT departm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Windows 7/Vista right below the managed by system administrator message is a link you can click that allows you to search for updates from Windows Updates.

The settings are specified via the GPO wish is most likely implemented by your corporate IT department. The only way to overridden this is to change the GPO directly, however this will get overridden the next time you connect to the corporate network.

The easiest way would be to request to be removed from the Windows Update group. However if you want to override it manually [this](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Registry-Keys-Tweaking-Windows-Update-Part1.html) article will give you the registry keys to edit to change it. You can also do it through the Local Policy Editor by following [these](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720539(WS.10).aspx) instructions.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the issue my modifying:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU]
"UseWUServer"=dword:00000000

If needed I could add this one to a startup script. Wonder why Microsoft didn't considered a value for using both (with fallback).

Comment: The latter will apparently be available in the next WSUS. Not sure when thought. The ability to manual select however is a good start.

Comment: Change the key in regedit like @sorin said, then restart the Windows Update service (via services.msc). I was getting another generic error (80070057) until I restarted the service.

Answer (score 4):

I maintain many machines in a domain environment. There are additional keys that may have to be modified to enable updates when disabled by policy.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU]
        "UseWUServer"=dword:00000000
```

and

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoWindowsUpdate+=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU]
    "UseWUServer"=dword:00000000
    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\WindowsUpdate]
"DisableWindowsUpdateAccess=dword:00000000 
"DisableWindowsUpdateAccessMode=dword:00000000
```

I saved the keys before changing and named it "DisableUpdates".  I then made the changes to parameters listed above and saved it as "EnableUpdates" and saved it to a USBDrive.  Double click the saved regkey of my choice, then StopStart the windows update service.  I now have an easy way of granular updating my users computers with Windows Update on a case by case basis. Sweet!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue (of a question [marked as a dupe](https://superuser.com/q/1113334/116475) of this one) by running the following `.reg`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\WindowsUpdate]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\WindowsUpdate]
```