# What causes Black Screen of Death after Windows Update Failure on Windows 7 x64(0x80070057)

Tags: windows-7, windows, updates, wsus

Receiving error **0x80070057** while performing Windows Updates on Windows 7 (64-bit).

Tried the following:

1. Ran [Windows Update Troubleshooter](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Open-the-Windows-Update-troubleshooter). It fixed several Registry problems, but still reports a problem with the aforementioned code.
2. Start > Run > cmd > net start WSUSService - This fails with 'The service name is invalid'
3. Set the 'UseWUServer' registry key (located under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU) to 'dword:00000000' as per another [SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/32340/how-to-enable-windows-update-over-the-internet-for-domain-computers-code-8024).
4. Reboot. Now, I no longer get an error message when I run WinUp but it does not succeed, and gives no error message.
5. Applied microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20858 - would not download UNTIL I DISABLED PEER BLOCK peerblock.com Once applied and rebooted, the downloads came tumbling in!
6. After updates applied, now I have a Black Screen of Death on reboot. Restart, go to Safe Mode which prompts for Recovery. After recovery, it hangs on an AVG antivirus DLL.
7. Get into Safe Mode again by persistence, found Explorer.exe was crashing. Ctrl-Alt-Esc didn't work, but by persistence with repeatedly restarting Explorer.exe from Ctrl-Alt-Del and Task Manager, I noticed [BatteryBar](http://osirisdevelopment.com/) was launching immediately before Explorer failed, and after removing BatteryBar's files under C:\Program Files\ I was able to restart without Safe Mode.

Applied Important and Critical updates with Windows Update, Black SOD returns. Rewind with multiple System Restores, going very slowly on Windows Update now.

Any idea of how I can determine which update causes the problem?

If there are log files, where would I find the useful ones?

Which are they?

What do I look for?

Comment: First Step....You need to uninstall AVG.    You will need to manually load the dlls ( there is an option to do this )

Comment: Have you tried to manually restart explorer.exe while at the "Black Screen of Death"

Comment: See 7. above. TY.

Comment: **Modifying the question to answer the question isn't the proper process to post an answer here at Superuser.**  Please post the answer to your question, in an answer, and leave your question as only the question.

Comment: Ramhound, you will notice I did not claim that as a solution. It's data, merely more information. Other StackExchange sites (e.g., askubuntu.com) _do_ welcome such updates. In any event, until the problem is solved and the system is stable after all Windows Updates, I will continue to post comments here. It is not stable, for I have had to back up and rewind with Windows Restore after the last set of updates. More data will follow.

Comment: The updates are fine.  I took your last update, as you solved the problem, which indicates it should be an answer not an update.

Answer (score 1):

Error '0x80070057' generally relates to a corruption within Windows (the parameter is incorrect).

I'd suggest following KB 947821 on Microsoft's website called **[Fix Windows corruption errors by using the DISM or System Update Readiness Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821)**, they provide a hot fix for this issue.

Comment: See # 5 above. Did not help.