# Windows Update: “Some settings are Managed by your system administrator”

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I want to turn off Windows Update on my machine (Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate). However, despite being logged in as an admin, Windows update complains " “Some settings are Managed by your system administrator". How can turn off Windows update?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Modify the group policy to allow the change, make the change, then change it back or simply set the setting in the register and/or the group policy.itself.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks indeed the issue seems to have the same root. I found a bunch of keys to modify, as I posted them as an answer.

Comment: For the "I want to turn off Windows Update on my machine (Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate)". . .  Why not just *stop* and *disable* the **Windows Update** service from `services.msc` rather than changing or deleting a bunch of registry keys? From an elevated command prompt.... **NET STOP wuauserv** and then **sc config wuauserv start= disabled** would do the trick via the non-GUI method... I typically try the built-in method first for the task and resort of registry HACKS as a last resort.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT Thanks, good to know! I simply used what I found first :-)

Comment: Frank - Have you rebooted your machine since these reg key deletions to see if they came back somehow like with GPO settings, etc.?

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT I rebooted (more exactly, the machine crashed once or twice), the settings didn't change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed the issue by running the following `.reg`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\WindowsUpdate]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\WindowsUpdate]
```

[image]